# Redirect the page from external website to web pages using play framework

Tags: frameworks, playframework-2.0, redirect

I am pretty much new to play framework and I am currently developing a website using this framework.

I have the following question:

Default page should be gmail.com and the once the user entered his credentials and if the user is authorized(I mean login successsful) then it should redirect to the my website along with the retrieval of user name.

To make it as simple:

say my website is www.hellow.com
Once the user enter hellow.com then it should redirect to gmail.com and once the gmail login is successful then it should come to hellow.com with the username.Though I am using redirect() but am not sure how to come back to my site once the login successful.

Currently I am using latest play version.

Please help me out.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It's not about redirect. You need to use Google API to be able to provide sign in with it. Start here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: can you post the piece of code in play to do this functionality. I mean redirect to gmail.com using the api and get back to my URL with the gmail username. i found couple of answers about this using http class but seems like this is not working in play 2.2.6

Comment: By assuming gmail api we have